# Как отобрать максимальные значения в группе строк?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, обработка-данных

Имею вот такой фрейм данных:

```
   cid     num      bdate        cost       payed       upto      pdate
0   29  233128 2021-06-05  15000.0000  15000.0000 2021-06-06 2021-06-06
1   29  233128 2021-06-05  15000.0000  15000.0000 2021-06-08 2021-06-06
2   30  233126 2021-06-07  35000.0000  35000.0000 2021-06-09 2021-06-07
3   30  233127 2021-06-07  25000.0000  25000.0000 2021-06-07 2021-06-08
4   30  233127 2021-06-07  25000.0000  25000.0000 2021-06-08 2021-06-08
```

Нужно по каждому `cid` найти такой `num`, у которого `pdate` максимальный.

Как это сделать? При группировке остаются лишние.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

если нужен только `num`:

```
In [86]: df.groupby("cid", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, "pdate")["num"])
Out[86]:
0    233128
3    233127
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

если нужны строки целиком:

```
In [87]: df.groupby("cid", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, "pdate"))
Out[87]:
   cid     num       bdate     cost    payed        upto      pdate
0   29  233128  2021-06-05  15000.0  15000.0  2021-06-06 2021-06-06
3   30  233127  2021-06-07  25000.0  25000.0  2021-06-07 2021-06-08
```

Answer (score 4):

Если мне не изменяет память, `groupby` сохраняет порядок строк исходного  фрейма в группе. Тогда можно сделать так:

```
df.sort_values("pdate").groupby("cid")["num"].last()
```

результат:

```
cid
29    233128
30    233127
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

Comment: все верно, в Pandas как и в Python используется стабильный алгоритм сортировки - `timsort`)